# function with receiver that iterates through some field of struct in go

Tags: go, struct, interface

i'm a Golang newbie trying to build a simple CLI. I'm converting an API call payload into an struct and want to format some information from this struct into a nice printable string. One of the informations i want to print is from an array of structs, like in this example:

```
type Pokemon struct {
    Abilities []struct {
        Ability struct {
            Name string `json:"name"`
            URL  string `json:"url"`
        } `json:"ability"`
        IsHidden bool `json:"is_hidden"`
        Slot     int  `json:"slot"`
    } `json:"abilities"`
    Height int    `json:"height"`
    ID     int    `json:"id"`
    Name   string `json:"name"`
    Types  []struct {
        Slot int `json:"slot"`
        Type struct {
            Name string `json:"name"`
            URL  string `json:"url"`
        } `json:"type"`
    } `json:"types"`
    Weight int `json:"weight"`
}
}
```

I'm trying to write a generic receptor function that iterates over some fields that are struct arrays and join its fields in a string. I can do a function that iterate specifically over some field like this:

```
func (p Pokemon) stringifyPokemonAbilities() string {
    var listOfAbilities []string
    for _, ability := range p.Abilities {
        listOfAbilities = append(listOfAbilities, ability.Ability.Name)
    }
    return strings.Join(listOfAbilities[:], " / ")
}
```

Returning e.g. `synchronize / inner-focus`

Working like this, i'll have to write almost the same function to the `Type` field. My question is, how to make this function more generic, accepting a field and iterating on it. Any thoughts?

Comment: The code in the question joins `Ability.Name`.  What's the criteria for deciding what to join?

Comment: To be able to iterate over the fields of arbitrary struct types you'll need to use reflection. https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do that using [relfect](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect?tab=doc). There is a well written [tutorial](https://blog.golang.org/laws-of-reflection), which you could have a look at.

According to the struct you give, I have written a demo. The main idea is
find the struct filed by name, then iterator the slice, find the name in the struct.

You could get the answer using `p.stringifyPokemon("Types")` or `p.stringifyPokemon("Abilities")` now.

```golang
func (p Pokemon) stringifyPokemon(field string) string {
    value := reflect.ValueOf(p)
    struct1 := value.FieldByName(field)

    if !struct1.IsValid() {
        return ""
    }

    if struct1.Type().Kind() != reflect.Slice {
        return ""
    }

    ans := make([]string, 0)

    for i := 0; i < struct1.Len(); i++ {
        slice1 := struct1.Index(i)
        if slice1.Type().Kind() != reflect.Struct {
            continue
        }

        for j := 0; j < slice1.NumField(); j++ {
            struct2 := slice1.Field(j)
            if struct2.Type().Kind() != reflect.Struct {
                continue

            }
            name := struct2.FieldByName("Name")
            if name.Kind() != reflect.String {
                continue
            }
            ans = append(ans, name.String())
        }
    }

    return strings.Join(ans[:], " / ")
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what i wanted. I hadn't dove into reflection package yet, but this blog article is very clear. Reflection is so powerful though